# Copy data feom one workbook to another depending on value

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy data from one excel workbook to another workbook depending on the value. Say I am having 2 excel workbooks named 1.xls & 2.xls. Thos look like below -

[image: Data of 1.xls]
[image: Data of 2.xls]

**What I need?**
Macro should read from 2.xls and in 1.xls where "a" is available, it should add "1" on NUMBER column, For "b" it should add as "2" .. like this. Final 1.xls should look like this -

[image: Final Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding VLOOKUP formula for the Col-B in 1.xls file.